# Java OpenCSV Split by pipe limited

Tags: java, opencsv, delimited

I am having an issue when reading from a file using comma split. I can read the file like this:

```
CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(FileName), '|' , '"' , 0);
```

Then when I want to get the individual values, I can read them like this:

```
String[] record = rowString.split(",");
```

The issue of course is that comma is not the most reliable way to read a file. Is there any way to split the string by pipe delimited like this?:

```
String[] record = rowString.split("\\|");
```

This is how I am reading the lines, it may possibly be in this code where I need to make such adjustment?

```
 for(String[] row : allRows){ 
   String rowString = Arrays.toString(row).toString(); 
   String[] record = rowString.split(","); 
 }
```

Thank you.

Comment: String[] record = rowString.split("\\|");  should work fine. But again, CSV files are commonly used for delimiting one-word strings. If your individual strings are multi-word, it makes sense to use a delimiter like a pipe to account for actual commas in the them.

Comment: What is the issue that you are facing? any stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this answer the question but in my case this solve the problem:

```
val reader: Reader = Files.newBufferedReader(path)

    val csvToBean = CsvToBeanBuilder<MyCsvSchema>(reader)
        .withType(MyCsvSchema::class.java)
        .withSeparator('|')
        .withIgnoreLeadingWhiteSpace(true)
        .build()

    val list = csvToBean.parse()
```

This is a Kotlin code

Comment: are you sure you set the separator on `CsvToBean`? In my case, it only worked when setting the separator on `CSVParser` (`new CSVParserBuilder().withSeparator('|')`)